# Ionic iframe zoom

Tags: ios, iframe, ionic-framework

I'm using an **iframe** in Ionic Framework to load an external website, in which i would like to be able to zoom the iframe content, my current code is:

```
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true" direction="xy" locking="false">
  <div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <iframe data-tap-disabled="true" onLoad="loadDone();" sandbox src="{{url}}"></iframe>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The css class:

```
.scroll-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I am testing in iOS (haven't tested on Android) and can't get the scrolling to work, I played around with no success. I also tried:

```
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true">
  <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" locking="false">
    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
      <iframe data-tap-disabled="true" onLoad="loadDone();" sandbox src="{{url}}"></iframe>
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just tested in android, zoom is not working either

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, kinda settled for no pinch to zoom